# Google Speech to Text on WAV file gives

Tags: ffmpeg, wav, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I am using the Google Speech to Text API to convert a WAV file to text. When I play the WAV file, it works fine but when I run the Google Speech To Text API I get this error:

```
WAV header indicates an unsupported format.
```

When I try to analyze the file using `ffmpeg` tool, it get the following error:

```
Output #0, wav, to '/home/shubham/workspace/intent-service/scripts/audio2.tmp.wav':
Metadata:
  ISFT            : Lavf57.83.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 pcm_s16le
[gsm_ms @ 0x55d4c255cd20] Packet is too small
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input size=7924kB time=00:08:27.16 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=3.72e+03x    
video:0kB audio:7924kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000961%
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the file encoding was NOT one of the supported types.. We used `ffmpeg` to change the encoding to mu-law and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for a .wav file you should add a flag that specifies its encoding as Linear16 by typing: --encoding=linear16.

The only other format compatible with Google STT API is .flac, and since you have ffmpeg, you can convert it to that and add a flag in your command --encoding=flac